# Cocoapods can't load image from Bundle

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I know this is a recurrent problem but all the posts I find are outdated...

I am simply trying to load an image in my cocoapods project, to an image. It is always `nil`

I copied my image close.png inside `MyPodProject/Assets`

```
s.resource_bundle = { 'MyPodProject' => 'MyPodProject/Assets/*.png' }

let view = UIImageView(frame: self.bounds)
let bundle = Bundle(for: Test.self)
let image = UIImage(named: "close", in: bundle, compatibleWith: nil)
```

The close image appears in a generated Resources folder in Xcode....
I tried everything for 3 hours...

Comment: Did you try: let image = Image Literal and than double clicking Image Literal to select the image?

Comment: No because my class is a @IBDesinable and I that wouldnt work

Comment: It's nice to see people downvoting without giving an explanation. Literally I tried anything to make this work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 s.resources = 'Hashtags/Assets/**/*.{png,storyboard}'
 s.resource_bundle = { 'Hashtags' => 'Hashtags/Assets/*.png' }
```

This is the only thing that worked... Combined to the code I pasted

```
let view = UIImageView(frame: self.bounds)
let bundle = Bundle(for: Test.self)
let image = UIImage(named: "close", in: bundle, compatibleWith: nil)
```